# Formatting numbers with smaller glyphs for decimals

Tags: fontsize, siunitx, numprint, decimal-number

I am currently writing up a coursebook in which I handle sets of decimal numbers. As the language of the coursebook is French, the decimal separator has to be a comma and the thousands separator a thin space. But then, it becomes difficult for the reader to distinguish between the set of four integers {0, 1, 2, 3} and the set of two decimal numbers {0.1, 2.3}. See the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\begin{document}
\noindent $\{\numprint{0.1}, \numprint{2.3}\}$\\
$\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$
\end{document}
```

which is rendered by

[image]

which is not quite fine…

What I would like to do is to print the comma and the decimals in a smaller font than the digits before the decimal separator (this is a rather common usage in France, for instance to typeset prices), like in

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
$\{\text{$0$\smaller$\mathord,1$},
\text{$2$\smaller$\mathord,3$}\}$\\
\end{document}
```

(yes, this is a quite ugly code :-S), which yields the much more easy-to-read

[image]

Now my question is: how to do that neatly with a simple command like `\numprint` from the `numprint` package? Changing the font for decimals does not seem to be a feature implemented in `numprint`, nor in `siunitx`; and I am not skilled enough in (La)TeX to build my own solution…

(Post-Scriptum: If possible, I would like to have a solution which also allows for inserting automatically the thousand separators, and rendering “1.2e3” with a power of ten…)

Comment: With the constraints given, I'd use a semicolon instead of a comma for lists.

Comment: Or, considered that you already need to type `\numprint` everywhere, you could just insert manual space after each comma in the list `$\{\numprint{0.1},\, \numprint{2.3}\}$`.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, I already had that idea in mind, but I do not like it much… :-| Also, I would find it quite frustrating that `numprint` and `siunitx` do implement some very sharp features to display formatted numbers, but that there would be no reasonable way to specify different fonts for pre- and post-comma digits… :-(

Comment: @RuixiZhang This is an idea worth being considered :-)

Comment: It might be frustrating; but I'm inclined to think that your readers will be more frustrated by the unreadable mess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx,relsize}

\sisetup{locale=FR}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hnum}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{.}}m}
 {
  \hnumA#1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hnumA}{mm}
 {
  \num{#1}
  \IfValueT{#2}{\hnumB{#2}}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hnumB}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{e}}m}
 {
  \hnumC#1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hnumC}{mm}
 {
  \ensuremath
   {
    {,}\mathsmaller{\num[add-integer-zero=false,output-decimal-marker={}]{.#1}}
    \IfValueT{#2}{{}\times\num{e#2}}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\{\hnum{0.1},\hnum{2.3},\hnum{4.5e10}\}$

\bigskip

$\{\num{0.1};\num{2.3};\num{4.5e10}\}$

\end{document}
```

However the result is really ugly and difficult to interpret. Much better to use a semicolon.

[image]

Comment: I definitely like this solution; it is GREAT! :-D Plus, it is rather easy to customize :-) (For instance, I also wanted to print the comma smaller to improve readability; and I managed to edit your solution this way in no time!).

Comment: @RémiPeyre For a smaller comma, just remove `{,}` and the `output-decimal-marker={}` option. This doesn’t improve much the final result, though.

Comment: Actually what I was saying in my previous message was that I _had_ found easily how to adapt your code, and that I enjoyed this feature of easy customization of your solution! ;-) (Another customization that I made was, before the comma, to go in text mode, use the text-mode `\smaller` command, and then go back to math mode: because `\mathsmaller` causes the smaller characters to be _quite_ small, which text-mode `\smaller` does not ;-)).

Answer (score 3):

How is this for a start?

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\numX#1.#2\relax{\mbox{$#1$\small$\mathord,#2$}}
\newcommand{\num}[1]{\numX#1\relax}

\begin{document}
  $\{\num{0.1}, \num{2.3}\}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do like it! :-) I had forgotten about this `\def\mycs#1.#2` TeX feature…

Comment: I'd consider `\ensuremath{#1{,}\mathsmaller{#2}}` exploiting `relsize` (but the result is ugly nonetheless).

Comment: @egreg Just a matter of taste! :-) Personally I much like this typographical rendering ;-)